# How to calculate the remaining amount per row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `wallet` table like this:

```
// wallet
+----+----------+--------+
| id | user_id  | amount |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | 5        | 1000   |
| 2  | 5        | -200   |
| 3  | 5        | -100   |
| 4  | 5        | 500    |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I want to make a `view` that calculates the remaining amount per row. Something like this:

```
+----+----------+--------+------------------+
| id | user_id  | amount | remaining_amount |
+----+----------+--------+------------------+
| 1  | 5        | 1000   | 1000             |
| 2  | 5        | -200   | 800              |
| 3  | 5        | -100   | 700              |
| 4  | 5        | 500    | 1200             |
+----+----------+--------+------------------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: @lucumt `sum()` of the previous rows.

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected result?

Comment: @Jens `sum()` of the upper (previous) rows.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: running sums can be made with the wndow function  SUM()

Comment: @jarlh `Server version: 8.0.20 - MySQL Community Server - GPL`

Comment: @nbk could you please give me a clue how can I do that using window functions?

Comment: @MartinAJ sure https://dbfiddle.uk/BNTZt4Gw

Comment: @nbk oh wow .. very good thx

Comment: @nbk I would advice your to reopen this question and post your answer

Comment: @nbk, question reopened. As requested by others, you can now post your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8 has window function for that purpose, like `SUM() OVER`

for your sample data, this will calculate the running SUM for every user_id

vital for th function to work is the `PARTITION BY` and the `ORDER BY` to get the right amount

The `PARTITION BY` is used to get sums for a user_id, so if you had user 5,6,7,8 it will correctly add (or subtract) the maount theat that user produced.

The `ORDER BY`is needed to get the right mount at the corect position. Tables are by nature unsortede, so an `ORDER BY` is needed to give the outout the corect order, if the ids where changed, you would get another mount, as it will be prior added to the running sum

```
SELECT
`id`, `user_id`, `amount`
, SUM(`amount`) OVER(PARTITION BY `user_id` ORDER BY `id`) run_sum
  FROM wallet
```

| id | user_id | amount | run_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2 | 5 | -200 | 800 |
| 3 | 5 | -100 | 700 |
| 4 | 5 | 500 | 1200 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BNTZt4Gw)

Comment: Can you provide a more detail explanation for `OVER(PARTITION BY `user_id` ORDER BY `id`)`,please?

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if this meets your demands or not

```
SELECT 
  t1.id,t1.user_id,t1.amount,
 (
  SELECT sum(t2.amount) FROM yourtable t2 WHERE t2.id<=t1.id AND t1.user_id=t2.user_id
) as remaning_amount
 FROM  yourtable t1
```

Comment: yeah looks ok .. lemme test it. thx

Comment: I'd add a user_id condition. (The danger of over-simplified sample data.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't there any approach using window functions?

Comment: @MartinAJ Sorry I am not familar with `windows function`, you can ask others for help